# Does setting setting movieclip.visible = true each frame use any extra resources?

Tags: actionscript-3

If something is visible, does calling

`movieclipname.visible = true;`

each frame do anything performance wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the item is already visible, then setting it visible at each frame will not produce any performance. From what I know there is a check inside and if the component is already visible then the call is ignored. But you make extra calls for the compiler which in any case is leading to lower performance.

If there is a high number of such components where you keep setting visible to true... then it may lead to performance issues.

Comment: I figured a work around so I don't have to call it each frame, but how much performance loss can be expected for a single call?

Comment: If it's just a single call per frame then that's ok, you do not have to worry about it, but it's good to know that it is the best to avoid this situations :) good luck!